# Use one thunderbolt port to connect to 2 monitors, one via usb-c 3.2 and another via hdmi

Tags: usb, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

there are a lot of similar questions, but none fits my use-case or answers me.

I just got a macbook pro 16 2021 (M1) from work and I'm wondering how to connect it with the rest of my setup to work from home.
I have a 1440p ultrawide monitor with usb-c 3.2 upstream, kvm and up to 90W (philips 346B1C) and a regular 16:9 1440p monitor with HDMI. I already connected the mac to both monitors with the thunderbolt port and the hdmi at the same time and they work fine, but I'm wondering if there is a hub/dock that I can use to connect to both monitors via one usb-c cable.

My objective is to have a clean desk and pull/retract only one cable to connect to the macbook pro; this hub/dock would connect via hdmi to the normal monitor and usb-c to the big monitor to pass image, power and maybe other usb devices.
Is this possible? Do you have any recommendations for hub/docs?

Nice-to-have: if I could connect to the hub with a long cable (instead of the small cables that usb hubs usually have) so I could hide the hub behind my desk along the other cables would be great!

**TLDR**: Looking for a thunderbolt passthrough dock/hub compatible with mackbook pro 16" 2021, to connect and power the macbook via usb-c 3.2 to one monitor and via hdmi to another.